# User & Groups settings text top down and reversed

Tags: macos, settings

When I go to settings -> user & groups then, all text and components in the container are reversed like the picture and clicking a component will not response anything.

It is shared mac mini with OS X Yosemite 10.10.2, I connected it with VNC client.

Logout and login do not help.

Can somebody help me how to fix it?

[image]

**Edit**

After reboot the mac, it is corrected.

Comment: Weird - that's either a joke or a virus. Google says nothing i can find about it.

Comment: Yes, this is one of the weirdest I've ever seen on the mac.

Comment: Well, considering that your user's names look weird (or did you censor them?) and that all the quotation marks (and extra characters) are random, I would call that a severe bug, unless you have installed something weird lately.

Comment: @awesomebing1, I am sorry I don't get it well about your comment, I don't censor anyone and I think all the quotation marks (and extra characters) are not random?! but reversed and top downed. I installed nothing lately.

Comment: @Chk0nDanger Okay. I still think something is weird here. Are any other panes breaking?

Comment: From a Google search, I found others where the icons were upside down, not all of the text.

Comment: @awesomebing1, I edited and it is corrected after reboot the mac. however I don't know why it happened. I found that general settings was broken like that, but other settings was fine.

Comment: @Chk0nDanger interesting. You may want to report this to Apple (bugreport.apple.com) with an Dev ID (developer.apple.com don't worry, it's free). Also, if a reboot solved it, add that as an answer.

Comment: @awesomebing1, OK, thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it happened but rebooting the mac solved this issue. I filed this issue to Apple.